# android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout could not be Found

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed the all of related question for this error and i tried :

**1**.changing the theme of the preview activity

//but I dont need this. It just changes the preview action bar (or other something) and I dont need this. (*material personal app_theme*)

**2**.change to API-21.
//This also fixes this error but we cannot see any action bar anymore with this option.

So, my Android Studio Version is:

```
1.2.1.1
```

I'm using API-22.

**Build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please add your gradle dependencies to the question.

Comment: @DanielNugent - added.check please.

Comment: Try updating to the latest support library and use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'`

Comment: @DanielNugent - updated to 22.1.1 (latest version) **but still problem exist.** :(

Answer (score 0):

After update the Android Studio to `AI 141.1962279` From **Canary** `Channel` and i added this one on the **Build.gradle** and it's seems work now.

> **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'**