# Material Navigation Drawer with recycle view and Card view

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I'm trying to use Below material navigation drawer from(**android4devs**) :

```
http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html
```

so, here is my main activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">
        </include>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and i need to do this like the below tutorial:

something like this on main activity:
https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7506/15428801864_5b4a709e38_b.jpg

i try this and other methods but i cannot show the cardview exactly on main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:contentPadding="16dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar">
            </include>

            <TextView
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Content here" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>








    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i think, there is a problem between

**Before add cardview :**

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tRXy.png
```

**Picture after the result (card view added):**

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAHtn.png
```

and there is a problem on my android studio preview, so i cant see this exactly but when i need to see the result, i had to run it on emulator...

My question about the preview and error:

[android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout could not be Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491113/android-support-v7-internal-widget-actionbaroverlaylayout-could-not-be-found)
and also on this main activity:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.
```

Build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.client.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
}
```

By the way,

How can i add this card view on MainActivity ?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you actually run the app? Did you get an error when you did that? Don't worry about the Preview. Android Studio is still not configured properly to show things like RecyclerView and CardView in it's preview window.

Comment: Your CardView is showing just fine. You can see that the Text inside of CardView(i.e Title and Content Here) are being displayed properly. I don't understand what your problem is?

Comment: main code : `http://i.stack.imgur.com/1tRXy.png` without problem on navigaation drawer.-  second code(with cardview): `http://i.stack.imgur.com/mAHtn.png` now, it's better to make a decision!

Comment: Where is your navigation drawer layout? The one which you pull from the left?

Comment: yes.as you can see in this tutorial:`www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html`

Comment: You should put the Toolbar at the top. You're putting it inside of the CardView. Do you really want that? CardView should be inside of the LinearLayout. CardView is suitable for holding Text and Images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your layout file to this and see if you notice any difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">
        </include>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         card_view:contentPadding="16dp"
         card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
         card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content here" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i just edited the code for showing end of the **DrawerLayout**.Thanks :)