# android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout Could Not be found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

After this error :

[android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout could not be Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491113/android-support-v7-internal-widget-actionbaroverlaylayout-could-not-be-found)

I cannot see `preview` of **My activity - Android Studio** with this Tutorial :

```
http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html
```

Im using latest version of android studio :`1.2.1.1`

here is my `Build.Gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.client.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
}
```

So, how can I fix this problem ?

What i tried ? : Rebuild and update to **appcompat-v7:22.1.1** but it doesnt solve the problem.

if i change this to `android.support.v7.widget.DrawerLayout` it says change to **V4**!.

Any solution is very much appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line inside your Build.gradle dependencies section

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
```

Comment: Can you run the project? Is it crashing? Or you just can't see the preview?

Comment: Oh, so you mean you just can't see the DrawerLayout in the preview window of Android Studio but the app is running just fine without any crash?

Comment: That is perfectly normal. Android Studio is currently not designed to display things like DrawerLayout, RecyclerView, CardView etc properly in it's Preview Window. It can only display things like ListView, TextView, ImageView etc. Maybe in the future updates, Android Studio will be able to show those things too but not at the moment. If your app is running, then there is nothing wrong with your code. Don't worry.

Comment: The preview window is buggy. Yes sometimes you can see CardView. You can see DrawerLayout too. But it doesn't work all the time. The point is, you shouldn't worry about your project just because you can't see it properly in the preview window. You need to run your app and see it for yourself.

Comment: Yes, you're right.so, this is about the google features, not us and i hope at the soon, google add this feature on yours android studio.thank you again.;)